# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\visiontutor\processregister1.php:39

Tags: wordpress, localhost

```php
?php
    $firstname =$_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
    $qualification=$_POST['qualification'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $phno=$_POST['phno'];
    $age=$_POST['age'];
    $gyear=$_POST['gyear'];
    $expierience=$_POST['expierience'];
    $proof=$_POST['proof'];
    $xxx=$_POST['xxx'];

    $myhost="localhost";
    $myname="root";
    $mypass="";
    $mydb="visiontutor";
    $conn =mysqli_connect($myhost,$myname,$mypass,$mydb) or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysqli_connect_error())
    {
       die('Connect Error('.mysqli_connect_errno().')'.mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    else
    {
      $SELECT="SELECT firstname from register Where firstname=? ";

      $INSERT="INSERT Into register 
    (firstname,lastname,qualification,email,phno,age,gyear,expierience,proof,xxx) values 
    (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($SELECT);
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$firstname);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($firstname);
    $stmt->store_result();
    $rnum=$stmt->num_rows;

    if($rnum==0)
    {
        $stmt->close();
        $stmt=$conn->prepare($INSERT);
        line39   $stmt->bind_param("ssssiiiisi",$firstname,$lastname,$qualification,$email,$phno,$age
        ,$gyear,$expierience,$proof,$xxx);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo"Registration successfull!! ";
    }
    else{
        echo"Registration  fail";
    }
    $stmt->close();
    }
    ?>
```

`line39` has error
 `bind_param` error on `localhost`
 this is a process code for registration form for an online tutorial website
 database name is `visiontutor`
 table name is `register`
 the table has following fields like firstname,lastname,qulification,email,phno,age,experience,proof
 graduated year etc

Comment: Which line is the error referring to in the supplied code?

Comment: Which line of that is line 39? You only seem to have provided about 20 lines...